# Benefit of creating a newbie or beginner tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, meta

I come across posts which revolve around basic troubleshooting. These posts usually get downvoted and not a lot of attention. However, users still need support, and plenty of people are willing and able to provide it because of the help we received as beginners. Additionally, there are basic computing concepts which are learned from basic troubleshooting.

Do you believe there is a benefit of creating a newbie tag to filter these sorts of questions. Maybe even implement it in a way so that newbie posts are not presented in the main question feed.

Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: it would just create a *de facto* novice ghetto

Comment: Which will clean up the question feed if implemented properly.

Comment: no, it would be a deteriment to SO.  the more knowledgeable looking for interesting or challenging questions would avoid/ignore those tags.  The result would be the blind leading the blind with bad answers to perhaps, even worse questions littering the site.  [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24398382/1070452)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93493/can-we-use-a-meta-tag-to-protect-newbies-from-abuse

Comment: You need to recognize the difference between questions that are not difficult and questions that are of low quality.  There is certainly plenty of overlap, but also plenty of quality questions that aren't hard, and plenty of low quality questions that are very hard.  If a question is of low quality *we don't want it here at all* no matter how easy or hard it is.  If a question is of high quality then it's a fine question that we want, again, regardless of whether or not it's easy or hard to solve.

Comment: Does *this question* really deserve so many downvotes?  IIRC, disagreeing with the OP isn't a reason to downvote.

Comment: @MattJohnson if it's a feature request, that's exactly what a downvote means. [Voting is different on meta.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @KevinB - Thanks! I hadn't seen that.

Comment: this is a bad idea, no a bad question, why so many downvotes?

Comment: @ncubica See Kevin's comment above.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

No, we don't need a [beginner] or [newbie] tag, because they are meta-tags.
[What is a meta-tag?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

> How can you tell you’re using a meta-tag? It’s easier than you might
> think.
>
> 1. If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag. Every tag you use should be able to work, more or
>    less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner],
>    [subjective], and [best-practices], are useless by themselves — they
>    tell you nothing at all about the content of the question.
> 2. If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag. In a cruel, ironic twist, the meaning of the
>    tag [subjective] itself … is actually subjective. Ditto for
>    [best-practices] and [beginner]. Best practices to whom? Beginner by
>    what criteria? These tags are impossible to define by anything
>    remotely resembling an objective metric. In comparison, the the
>    meaning of tags like [java], [c#], and [javascript] are crystal clear
>    to all but the nuttiest of nutbags.

[Meta-tags are burninated some time ago](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), and meta-tagging is explicitly discouraged now.

Comment: Thanks. Its good to understand the rationale behind the decision.

Comment: I think the idea for 'beginner' tag is good. I was preparing to post such topic and found this one. The only special thing which is necessary is that this tag must be assigned by readers. It is optional for author but everybody can check: "[x] This questions is from beginner".

Comment: The newbie tag need not be for "newbies". In a few very small areas I am competent but I am a newbie in CSS, jQuery, PhpStorm etc etc. So I might ask a sensible question and be OK but I might want to ask a question that the really knowledgeable find stupid. **ALSO** 99% of questions here are greek to me but I could help out with some of the simpler ones.