# Graded levels of questions

Tags: discussion, tags

Reading down the questions on Stack Overflow, some of the questions can be put into a 'basic' / 'introductory' level of programming. Would it be worth having such a tag?

Personally I think reading a book will help more, but if users are going to come to SO to ask basic questions, (they are an audience that can be sold to with relevant adverts on the stack exchange sites) then such a tag may encourage them to read other basic/introductory level questions for the language they're studying (either from related questions, or just subscribing to the tag?).

Yes, I understand it will be difficult to differentiate between introductory / non-introductory questions, but I think some differentiation will be better than none.

Comment: See ["Benefit of creating a newbie or beginner tag"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261526/benefit-of-creating-a-newbie-or-beginner-tag), where a similar argument was made.

Comment: `Personally I think reading a book will help more` -- 'Nuff said?

Comment: If no differentiation is to be made, do questions about basic variables, argument passing etc really belong on SO? Such questions will be answered for the 'rep' but a basic programming online guide would answer the question. A close reason of 'too-basic' seems a bit, maybe arrogant

Comment: @RobertHarvey However, people will come to the site with such questions, and from the perspective of site income, can be advertised to so seems silly to turn them away.

Comment: "If no differentiation is to be made, do questions about basic variables, argument passing etc really belong on SO?" yes, assuming they meet the criteria for a good and useful question. Though, they are normally dupes and should be closed as such (or whatever reason fits).

Comment: still don't understand why so many downvotes. Is it a poor question? Do they disagree? Did they not have any icecream today?

Comment: We "grade" questions using the up and downvote arrows.

Comment: @CodyGray "grade"... doesn't mean what you think it means. Ability and quality are two very different things.

Comment: I guess I don't get it. If they're good questions, then you upvote them. If they're not, downvote them. What difference does it make whether it is "easy"? All that means is that you already know the answer—so answer it already.

Answer (score 6):

"Introductory" programming is very subjective and relative.  I feel that this would be very hard to implement, simply because people learn differently and start on different topics.

For example, I taught myself rudimentary Java, and started with Android programming.  However, I'll be damned if I have to write any sort of arithmetic in Java.  This is the opposite to most "Intro to Java" books and publications, because they have you starting with command-line stuff, and adding numbers and such.